# Is copy paste programming sometimes allowed?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have class named `GeneticOperator` which is responsible for mutation and crossover operators in genetic program. I have different functions for different mutation and one public function for mutation, where i have switch statement for type. In function `random()` I rand mutation type and number of genes to mutate in chromosome.

```
class GeneticOperator
{
public:
    enum MutationType
    {
        FUNCTION_MUTATION,
        ARGUMENTS_MUTATION,
        WORSTGENES_MUTATION //not implemented yet
    };
    enum CrossoverType //not implemented yet
    {
        ONEPOINT_CROSSOVER,
        TWOPOINT_CROSSOVER,
        UNIFORM_CROSSOVER,
        BESTGENE_CROSSOVER
    };
public:
    GeneticOperator();
    //GeneticOperator(const GeneGenerator* geneGenerator,
    //                int maxNGene);


    ChromosomePtr mutation(const Chromosome& parent) const;

private:
    void random();

    ChromosomePtr functionMutation(const Chromosome& parent) const;
    ChromosomePtr argumentsMutation(const Chromosome& parent) const;
private:
    const GeneGenerator* geneGenerator_;
    MutationType mutationType_;
    CrossoverType crossoverType_;
    int nMutatedGene_;
    int maxNMutatedGene_;
};
```

functions:

```
ChromosomePtr GeneticOperator::mutation(const Chromosome &parent) const
{
    if (parent.getSize() < maxNMutatedGene_)
    {
        throw "Za malo genow w chromosomie";
    }
    this->random();
    switch(mutationType_)
    {
    case FUNCTION_MUTATION:
        return functionMutation(parent);

    case ARGUMENTS_MUTATION:
        return argumentsMutation(parent);

    case WORSTGENES_MUTATION:
        //not implemented yet
        break;

    default:
        throw "Bad enum type";
        break;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

ChromosomePtr GeneticOperator::functionMutation(const Chromosome &parent) const
{
    ChromosomePtr child = parent.copy();

    for(int i = 0; i < nMutatedGene_; i++)
    {
        GenePtr newGene = nullptr;
        int geneNumber = rand() % (parent.getSize() - 1);

        switch(parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getType())
        {
        case Gene::TERMINAL_GENE:
            i--;
            break;

        case Gene::FUNCTION_GENE:
            int nArguments = parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getNArguments();
            GenePtr randomGene = move(geneGenerator_->getRandomFunctionGene(nArguments));
            for(int k = 0; k < nArguments; k++)
            {
                randomGene->addChild(parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getChild(k));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return child;
}

ChromosomePtr GeneticOperator::argumentsMutation(const Chromosome& parent) const
{
    ChromosomePtr child = parent.copy();

    for(int i = 0; i < nMutatedGene_; i++)
    {
        GenePtr newGene = nullptr;
        int geneNumber = rand() % (parent.getSize() - 1);

        switch(parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getType())
        {
        case Gene::TERMINAL_GENE:
            i--;
            break;

        case Gene::FUNCTION_GENE:
            GenePtr randomGene = move(parent.getGene(geneNumber)->clone());
            int nArguments = parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getNArguments();
            for(int k = 0; k < nArguments; k++)
            {
                int childGeneNumber = rand() % geneNumber;
                randomGene->setChild(childGeneNumber, k);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```

`functionMutation()` and `argumentsMutation()` looks like copy paste programming.

How can I avoid it? I tried to return only `GenePtr` in this functions, but then method `mutation()` isn't clear.

What would you advise?

Comment: If they are doing exactly the same thing, have one function call the other.    If they have some parts in common, put the common parts in separate functions, and call those separate functions from both `functionMutation()` and `argumentsMutation()` as needed.

Comment: Off topic: If you are trying for scientific rigor, I recommend replacing `rand` with the much more random [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

The copy pasted methods are actually just cluttered with unnecessary code. My solution to get rid of the duplication would be to add a function to get a random function gene from the parent gene. This would also clarify the purpose of the functions.

```
GenePtr GeneticOperator::getRandomFuncGene(const Chromosome &parent) const
{
    while(true)
    {
        int geneNumber = rand() % (parent.getSize() - 1);
        if (parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getType()) 
        {
            return parent.getGene(geneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the new method and after removing the clutter, the old functions look like this:

```
ChromosomePtr GeneticOperator::functionMutation(const Chromosome &parent) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nMutatedGene_; i++)
    {
        GenePtr funcGene = getRandomFuncGene(parent);

        int nArguments = funcGene->getNArguments();
        GenePtr randomGene = move(geneGenerator_->getRandomFunctionGene(nArguments));
        for(int k = 0; k < nArguments; k++)
        {
            randomGene->addChild(funcGene->getChild(k));
        }
    }

    return parent.copy();
}

ChromosomePtr GeneticOperator::argumentsMutation(const Chromosome& parent) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nMutatedGene_; i++)
    {
        GenePtr funcGene = getRandomFuncGene(parent);

        GenePtr randomGene = move(funcGene->clone());
        int nArguments = funcGene->getNArguments();
        for(int k = 0; k < nArguments; k++)
        {
            int childGeneNumber = rand() % geneNumber;
            randomGene->setChild(childGeneNumber, k);
        }
    }

    return parent.copy();
}
```

I hope I did not misunderstand the code, but it was quite difficult to guess what is going on sometimes.

There are also some other problems with these functions. As far as I could understand the return values did not correspond with the actual purpose of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question's title

> ### Is copy paste programming sometimes allowed?

No. It's error prone<sup>1</sup> from the bone (hey that rhymes).

> How can I avoid it?

The usual way to avoid copy/paste implementations is to provide template functions or classes that factor out the type unspecific code.

The type specific code can be refactored to type specialized function calls.

---

<sub>1) There are even made extensive efforts from static code analysis tools to detect copied/copy modified code, and warn about potential errors copied along.

The really good tools to detect this with least false positives are pretty expensive, so just don't do it.</sub>

Comment: The downvoter might want to explain themselves what's wrong with this answer thoroughly please!

Comment: Copy paste is correct when you want the first version and the second version to be fully decoupled from each other in future development. I was the 2nd (?) downvote and I probably wouldn't downvote if your answer weren't so absolute.

Comment: @djechlin _"when you want the first version and the second version"_ Huh? A copy applies to a specific iterative code pattern, regardless of the symbol names. There are no _versions_ of these patterns.

Comment: You copy code from Foo.java somewhere into Bar.java when you want the copy of the code living on Foo.java to be fully decoupled from the copy of the code in Bar.java.

Comment: @djechlin Well fine, you copy buggy code from `Foo.java` somewhere into `Bar.java` and since these are decoupled now, you need to remember to fix the bug twice that you just had detected in `Foo.java`. That's why copy/paste is a no no, unless you are a 100% sure (who ever is?) what you are doing.

Comment: Was I supposed to explain why I downvoted or do I also need to argue incessantly?

Answer (score -2):

```
ChromosomePtr GeneticOperator::mutation(const Chromosome &parent, string type) const
{

    ChromosomePtr child = parent.copy();

    for(int i = 0; i < nMutatedGene_; i++)
    {
        GenePtr newGene = nullptr;
        int geneNumber = rand() % (parent.getSize() - 1);

        switch(parent.getGene(geneNumber)->getType())
        {
        case Gene::TERMINAL_GENE:
            i--;
            break;

        case Gene::FUNCTION_GENE:
            if(type == "function"){
                functionM(parent);
            }else if(type == "argument"){
                argumentM(parent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```

Comment: Code with no further explanation?

Comment: It is self explanatory :)